# Rearranging Asp.net Panels

Tags: asp.net

Please Help me, How to rearrange set of asp.net panels (or Divs) in C#

Let me explain the scenario:

I have 10  static asp.net Panels. Each panel have many controls(max:8) in it.
Based on the setting (from DB), I need to arrange (reordering) those divs and render to the page.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say you have 3x options

1)  Add panels to user controls (as described in Dante's answer). This is simplest if you have many controls but few pages

2) Build the panels dynamically and add the child controls to the panels. This would be simpler if you have few controls and many pages - adding child controls based on a switch statement or similar.

3) Render the page with all panels in the same order and then reorder the divs using client side javascript based on the database order.

Comment: Thanks Justin & Dante for your Help.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your panels in User Controls and load them dynamically in code. The order in which you load them is the order in which they will be displayed.

To load the user control:

```
Control myUserControl = (Control)Page.LoadControl("MyUserControl.ascx");
somePlaceHolder.Controls.Add(myUserControl);
```

Comment: Thanks Dante, Is there any other solution ?

Comment: Lets Say, I am having 100+ asp.net Panels. We cant create 100+ usercontrols. right ?

Comment: Why can't you? You still have to write their html, either directly in the page or in user controls. User controls give you some extra flexibility...